# Is there a tool that can be used to simulate credit card payments?

Tags: simulation, online-payment

I am writing a desktop application using Java Swings. I need to simulate credit card payments so that with sample credit card numbers a real payment (card apparently processed and response received) could be simulated. Is there any free tool or software that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that via [Paypal Developer Tools](https://developer.paypal.com/).

Specifically with a [Sandbox Test Account](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/) and the paypal [API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/).

It will be from your end the same as a real paypal credit card transaction. I haven't used it with Java so I can't comment on any specific tricks to make it work best for that. If after reading those docs you get stuck at all I'd suggest [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) on SO.

Comment: Souncds greta, and I will use it, but, even though it was accepted as the ansewer, it doesn't answer the OP's question. Do you know of anything similar for credit cards? Thanks in advance.